# How do I get data from a rectangle in D3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, d3.js

I have this mock up of something I'm working on at the moment :

http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/5760/

Basically I've created 3 rectangles with 3 circles on top, in my own work there's around 80. What I want to do is compare these rectangles to check which ones have the same number.

I've worked with the nodes in force layout so normally I would go through them like so :

```
     rectangles.forEach(function(e){

        console.log(e.Number) // to get that rectangles number

        var compareRect = rectangles.filter(function(n){ return n.Number === e.Number});

        if(e.Connect === compareRect.Connect){
        //colour corresponding circles green
        }
        else{
        //colour corresponding circles red
        }
        });
```

I can't even log to console as this gives me undefined.

I want to get at the rectangles data so I can first compare their Number, then once the numbers are the same, check if the 'Connect' value is the same. If it is, then colour the circles on both the same numbered rectangles Green, if the 'Connect' value is different, then colour the circles Red.

Hope this makes sense, basically I can't get hold of the data for any of the rectangles I have created. Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note, that your variable `rectangles` is a [d3 selection](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections) which is a two-dimensional array containing grouped references to your `rect`s. You are, however, using `Array.prototype.forEach()` to iterate over the the array.

```
rectangles.forEach(function(e){
    console.log(e.Number) // to get that rectangles number
});
```

While being technically and syntactically correct, this won't give you the expected behaviour. To iterate over your rectangles you should use [`selection.each(function)`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#each) instead:

```
rectangles.each(function(e){
    console.log(e.Number) // to get that rectangles number
});
```

See this working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/5765/).